# how to retrive value from property file which are present outside of the app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

working on one application in which i want to retrieve values from property files which are present outside of the application i.e on system drive. but while doing this i am facing the problem.Interestingly if i put property files at class path location then application works. I am using resin server 4.0.23 and mvc architecture with spring 2.5.4 jars.i am also tried it on resin upgraded version of resin 4.0.9. there also i am getting the same problem.

Is there is any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a properties file from an arbitrary path on the system you need to do something like

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(somefilename));
```

If you are trying to load the properties file with calls to getResource() or getResourceAsStream(), your properties file should be somewhere accessible from a ClassLoader, usually on the classpath. Check the docs for Class.getResource and ClassLoader.getResource